# Wordpress error Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, wordpress

I receive the following  notice
Undefined offset: 0 in.........

```
Category: <?php $category = get_the_category(); 
                    if($category[0]){ 
                    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->term_id ).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a>'; } 
                ?>
    | <?php comments_popup_link( 'Add a comment', '1 comment', '% Comments' ); ?>
</div>
```

The error is on this line

```
if($category[0]){
```

How to fix the notice.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning, and it means there is not a $category[0], meaning your $category most likely is empty or does not contain an array..

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: double check your array

Comment: Your array is empty. You have to add categories from dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isset check if a Variable is undefined or NULL and return false [Function isset() on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(isset($category) && isset($category[0])) {
    ...
}
```

or faster and same logic:

```
if(isset($category, $category[0])) {
  
}
```